# TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, hash, typeerror

Hi I am building a an app with rails and angular. I keep on getting a type error executing this code

```
$scope.makeTip = function(tip){
    data = {
      tip: { 
        bookies: tip.bookies, 
        user_id: $scope.currentUser.id
      }, 
      prediction: $scope.madePredictions
    },
    $http.post('/tips.json', data).success(function(data){
      console.log(data)
    });
  };
  $http.get('/predictions/fixtures_this_week').success(function(response){
    $scope.fixturesThisWeek = response.data;
  });

  //Updating the scores the dependent of on the type of bet id
  $scope.addPrediction = function(prediction, fixtureId) {
    data = {};
    data.fixtureId = fixtureId;
    data.predictionGoalsHomeTeam = prediction.scores.predictionGoalsHomeTeam[fixtureId];
    data.predictionGoalsAwayTeam = prediction.scores.predictionGoalsAwayTeam[fixtureId];
    data.typeOfBet = prediction.typeOfBetId[fixtureId];
    $scope.madePredictions.push(data);
    console.log($scope.madePredictions)
  }
}]);
```

However I believe the problem stems from the method  in my tips controller, possibly on the 4th line down

```
def create
    @tip = Tip.new(params[:tip])
    @tip.save
    @prediction = Prediction.find(params[:prediction][:fixtureId])
    @prediction.predictionGoalsHomeTeam = params[:prediction][:predictionGoalsHomeTeam]
    @prediction.predictionGoalsHomeTeam = params[:prediction][:predictionGoalsAwayTeam]
    @prediction.save
    @tip.predictions << @prediction
    respond_with(@tip)
  end
```

Does anyone have any idea about how I can approach this type error?

Thanks

Comment: That's a Rails error. If you're seeing an error referencing line 4 in the file you're showing with the `create` method, that would mean `Prediction.find` is receiving a symbol, when it needs an integer. Add a `to_i` method to the end of the params call. All just guesswork, though, without seeing an error and knowing your file names and line numbers.

Comment: Hi the error is in the title, sorry I didn't specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of errors.. Inside your create method you are assigning @prediction.predictionGoalsHomeTeam twice in a row.

```
@prediction.predictionGoalsHomeTeam = params[:prediction][:predictionGoalsHomeTeam]
@prediction.predictionGoalsHomeTeam = params[:prediction][:predictionGoalsAwayTeam]
```

So you need to change the last one to AwayTeam as that is what you are getting from the params.

Your main issue is that params[:prediction] is an array so `Prediction.find(params[:prediction][:fixtureId])` won't work as you are trying to grab the fixtureId of that array which doesn't exist. You need to loop through the `params[:prediction]` and store each object in `@tip.predictions` individually. Try using this:

```
  def create
    @tip = Tip.new(params[:tip])
    @tip.save
    params[:prediction].each do |p|
      @prediction = Prediction.find(p[:fixtureId])
      @prediction.predictionGoalsHomeTeam = p[:predictionGoalsHomeTeam]
      @prediction.predictionGoalsAwayTeam = p[:predictionGoalsAwayTeam]
      @prediction.save
      @tip.predictions << @prediction
    end
    respond_with(@tip)
  end
```